# Using "IN" operator in a dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, in-operator

i've been searching SO for a while and found nothing related to this.

We use heavily the dynamic approach for most of our queries like this:

```
Declare @ContactId VarChar(8000)

Select @ContactId = '1'

Select * 
From Person.Contact
Where 1 = 1 And 
Case When Len(Ltrim(Rtrim(@ContactId))) = 0 Then 1 Else ContactID End =
Case When Len(Ltrim(Rtrim(@ContactId))) = 0 Then 1 Else @ContactId End
```

This way the query gets filtered dynamically if there's a value on the parameter

But the problem comes when trying the same stuff with several IDs like so:

```
Declare @ContactId VarChar(8000)

Select @ContactId = '1,2,3'

Select * 
From Person.Contact
Where 1 = 1 And 
Case When Len(Ltrim(Rtrim(@ContactId))) = 0 Then 1 Else ContactID End In (
Select Case When Len(Ltrim(Rtrim(@ContactId))) = 0 Then 1 Else ( Select id From dbo.SplitString(@ContactId,',') ) End )
```

Sql throws an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

that's totally normal and expected, my question is:

Is there a way to dynamically do this kind of filtering ?

The solution we use is this:

```
Declare @Table Table(
    Col1    Int,
    Col2    Int,
    Col3    Int
)

Insert @Table
Select Col1, Col2, Col3
From Person.Contact
Where [many filters except the in clause filters]

If Len(Ltrim(RTrim(@ContactId))) > 0
    Select * 
    From @Table
    Where ContactId In ( Select Id From dbo.SplitString(@ContactId, ',') )
Else 
Select *
From @Table
```

But it's not an option when the query is massive and feeding a table variable is overkill for this. Hope i made my point and someone is kind enough to help me find a solution to this.

PS: Using `sp_ExecuteSql` is not an option in this scenario either, sorry.

Comment: If you rule out the two ways that you would do something, then yes, you're going to have a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you *should* do this is with a table parameter.

But if you want to persist in this approach.

```
Declare @ContactId VarChar(8000) 

Select @ContactId = '1,2,3'
Select *  
From Person.Contact 
where ',' + @contactID + ',' like '%,'+convert(varchar(50),contactid)+',%'
```

Comment: This approach is interesting enough, but the sad part is that it's not selecting anything if the parameter is empty :(

Comment: @SamCcp add an `or len(@contactID)=0`

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere, by adding that condition, it does bring the desired data even when the parameter is empty, but i can't play with many conditions like this right? I mean how could i search for another condition say... @EmailPromotion = '1,2'

Comment: @SamCcp Sure you can. Stick ( around the like / or ) and add as many other filters as you like. eg: `and (','+@emailpromotion+',' like '%,' + emailpromotion + ',%')`

Comment: Yeah, i just figured it out, thanks, i'll run some queries and test the performance, in the meantime, you sir earned a fan. Thanks.

Comment: I can tell you it won't be especially quick. :) That's why you should use a table parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * 
From Person.Contact
Where (
           len(@contactid) > 0 AND 
           ContactID IN (Select id From dbo.SplitString(@ContactId,','))) 
or 1 = 1
```

Comment: Same stuff than previous answer, it doesn't display anything if the parameter is empty and the OR part must be omitted because it brings all the rows on the table.